# Why is this build failing when NODE_ENV is set to production?

Tags: node.js, npm

I was having trouble getting `npm install` to work when `NODE_ENV` was set to `production`, and since I don't have enough depth in Node to understand what was going wrong, I thought I'd ask why that might be the case.

For context:

- This project uses node 18.14.2
- `package.json` includes a script called `prepare` that simply runs
  `husky install`, and that's executed as part of `npm install`.
- When `NODE_ENV` is set to its default value `development`, `npm install` to complete successfully:

  ```
  file-upload git:(ACW-5868) ✗ export NODE_ENV=development
  file-upload git:(ACW-5868) ✗ npm install                

  > @icpsr/file-upload@0.1.29 prepare
  > husky install

  husky - Git hooks installed

  added 1397 packages, and audited 1845 packages in 5s

  236 packages are looking for funding
    run `npm fund` for details

  5 moderate severity vulnerabilities

  To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
    npm audit fix --force

  Run `npm audit` for details.
  ```
- However, when it's set to `production`, I get this:

  ````
  file-upload git:(ACW-5868) ✗ export NODE_ENV=production
  file-upload git:(346b304) npm install

  > @icpsr/file-upload@0.1.29 prepare
  > husky install

  sh: husky: command not found
  npm ERR! code 127
  npm ERR! path /Users/bhorvath/tmp/file-upload
  npm ERR! command failed
  npm ERR! command sh -c husky install```
  ````

What is going on here? Why is node unable to find an executable that's within the root directory structure when the build is run in a `production` environment? (Not that you'd necessarily want to do so btw; I'm just curious.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably ran `npm install husky --save-dev` to install that package (as the official documentation suggest: https://typicode.github.io/husky/getting-started.html#manual).

`--save-dev` installs packages used only for development, that's why you cannot run it in a production environment.

You can check it by opening your `package.json` file and check if `husky` is under `devDependencies`.

To use `husky` in a production environment, you can refer to the official doc: https://typicode.github.io/husky/guide.html#disable-husky-in-ci-docker-prod

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense - `husky` is in the `devDependencies` of `package.json`, so I'm sure someone working on the codebase did so at one point or another.

Comment: Also, check this: https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/914

There are few solutions (and a lot more, if you google something like `npm husky production`) to use husky in production

Comment: And, of course, the official doc: https://typicode.github.io/husky/guide.html#disable-husky-in-ci-docker-prod